# Access a built-in mac webserver from another machine

Tags: macos, networking, apache-http-server, php

I'm using php to create a built-in web server in my Mac, so I can access my webpage files and route them through a file. In order to do this, I'm using the terminal command `php -S localhost:8080 routing.php`.

When I'm with my Mac, I can access `http://localhost:8080` and I can successfully see my application, but if I go into another machine in my network and access `http://myip:8080` or `http://my-Mac-adress.local:8080`, I can't access my application...
So, my question is: how can I access my application with another computer in the same network?

And also, is it possible to configure apache so I don't have to start my server with `php -S localhost:8080 routing.php` every time I want to access it? The problem is that I'm using silex to accomplish a routing and a clean-url system, so I have to route the access to the `routing.php` file...

Finally, I'm sorry if I haven't explained myself clearly; I'm really a begginer with all these things of web servers.
Thanks!

Comment: `which -a php` are running on your Mac? I ask, because `Silex` depends on `php5`. This will effect the path of `libphp.so` in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you’re telling the PHP built-in webserver to listen on `localhost`, it won’t be accessible remotely. Try `0.0.0.0` or `*` instead of `localhost`.

Apache isn’t involved in your current setup at all, or you left that part out in your question.

Using Apache is certainly possible, typically you’d use mod_php. There are plenty of guides available on how to set it up.

Silex most likely ships with a `.htaccess` for use with Apache and mod_rewrite. Having it in your web application’s top level directory should ensure proper routing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

#### Enable Websites

Easiest way to share your Sites: Enable `Web Sharing` in `System Preferences`.

There is a build-in Apache running on your Mac.

#### Config your apache

To configure your Apache, you should check the files located at `/etc/apache2/`.

- `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` will configure the apache in general
- `/etc/apache2/users/` contain files for `per-user` configuration

  Inside of file `yourname.conf` you would add

  ```
  <IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
  </IfModule>
  ```

To **enable** `php` on your Apache, you would need to **add** a file like `/etc/apache2/others/php55.conf`

Inside this file you will load the php-module like this

```
LoadModule php5_module    libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

#### control your apache

besides System Preferences from `commandline` invoke

```
    sudo apachectl { start | restart | stop }
```